# Error body deserialization

Tags: android, retrofit2

Is there a particular reason why retrofit does not try to deserialize response's body if its code is in 400-599 range? I am well aware that you have to convert the error yourself, but it would be nicer if I wouldn't have to do that myself, especially when such conversion would halt the UI thread.

Would it be possible to add a response adapter for such cases?

Comment: it is possible. https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1321

Comment: That's converting it yourself, not adding an adapter. I already stated that I'm doing that already.